# Is is necessary to close the input stream returned from HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets

I've got some production code that does something like:

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest
...
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(httpServletRequest.getInputStream())
```

These streams are never closed explicitly. I'm assuming here that the servlet container manages this (JBOss Web). What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I originally asked this question because I was running into a problem with JBoss Web 2.1.2 (in JBoss 5.0.1). The ChunkedInputFilter can loop forever when processing chunked transfer-encoding. I thought it was my code. There is a fix for this in JBoss Web 2.1.3.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The thumb rule in I/O is, if you did not open/create the inputstream source **yourself**, then you do not necessarily need to close it as well. Here you are just wrapping the request's inputstream, so you don't necessarily need to close it.

If you did open the input yourself by e.g. `new FileInputStream("c:/file.ext")` then you obviously need to close it yourself in the finally block. The container ought to do so under the hood.

Comment: if the method you're calling start's with `open` like `openStream` from java.net.URL, does that mean you opened it yourself and need to close it too?

Comment: I guess one exception is if the new stream you opened is just a wrapper: `new BufferedInputStream(inputStream)` then you might not need to close it because it should be closed by whoever opened `inputStream` ?

Comment: I guess we have an exception with `URLConnection getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` as the oracle documentation states [(Oracle Doc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) the stream seems to be opened implicitly. Also this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844535/why-do-you-have-to-call-urlconnectiongetinputstream-to-be-able-to-write-out-to) describes that you have to close the stream even tho you just called `get...Stream()`

Comment: @tobi: You don't need to close its output stream (request body), it will implicitly be done when you get its input stream (response body). The close of input stream is also not strictly necessary, it will implicitly be done when it times out; you have at that point already read it anyway. This does however not mean that it's not considered good practice to close them anyway.

Answer (score 11):

You should absolutely *not* close these streams yourself, that is the container's job. Doing so manually risks interfering with the request lifecycle, and some containers may object violently to you doing this.

Comment: "some containers may object violently": can you provide references?

Answer (score 3):

The container will handle this. **It is always good coding style to close resource in the same place you allocated it.** (I was wrong on that in my original post. I thought you opened the stream. Should read more carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

The specification (up to the 3.0 candidate) does not say (as far as I can tell). In the absence of canonical information, you might be at the mercy of the implementation.

The source code for the reference implementation is mentioned on the [Sun Servlet page](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/):

> The reference implementation is included in the Java EE 5 SDK and also in the open-source Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) application server, available through the GlassFish project, on java.net. The reference implementation source code for Servlet technology is available from the svn repository on java.net. Additional information on all webtier technologies in GlassFish can be found at the GlassFish Webtier page.

Checking the behaviour may be as close to a definitive answer as you'll get.