# How to close a Stream of a REST Service?

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I need to make a java REST service that will return an inputstream as a response. My problem is that I don't know how to close the stream after the client receives the entire stream. I'm using Java and CXF. Thanks

```
@GET
@Path("/{uuid}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getAttachmentByUuid(@PathParam("uuid")String uuid)
{
 //getting inputstream from AWS S3
 InpputSream is=getStreamFromS3(uuid);
 return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(is).build();
 // will this "is" stream causes memory leak,, do I have to close it. Client side is not controlled by me
}
```

Comment: Why not just `close()` the stream?How are you processing the stream at client side? Do You have errors? Please, post the code and the exception traces

Comment: Please supply the code you have developed thus far.

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JAX-RS is implemented using Java servlets. In case of CXF is used `CXFServlet`.   Your stream will be sent to client using the `HttpServletResponse` of the servlet interface

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

**You should not close an stream source** (`HttpServletResponse`) if you have not created it. It is responsability of the container, and you can interfere with the life cycle of the request

See also [Is is necessary to close the input stream returned from HttpServletRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808248/is-is-necessary-to-close-the-input-stream-returned-from-httpservletrequest)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stream to close, consider try with resources:

```
@GET
@Path("/{uuid}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getAttachmentByUuid(@PathParam("uuid")String uuid)
{
 //getting inputstream from AWS S3
 // the try block opens the stream and guarantees to close it
 try (InputStream is=getStreamFromS3(uuid)) {
     return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(from(is)).build();
 }
}
```

This requires Java 7 and onwards. It's also awesome!

If you're in Java 6, then you would have to make your own finally block to remember to close the stream for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking to use a 'Conduit'
See [CXF Apache Custom Transport](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/custom-transport.html) for more info.
Be Careful though, the documentation states :

> It is strongly recommended to don’t break streaming in Conduit and Destination implementations, if physical protocol supports it. CXF is completely streaming oriented – it causes high performance and scalability.